# count duplicate int in C#

Tags: c#

I want it to be (eg: "2" is occurs 10 time(s)).
Can anyone help?

```
var q = from x in wordlist
        group x by x into g
        let count = g.Count()
        orderby count descending
        select new { Word = g.Key, Count = count };


string keyword = "";

foreach (var x in q)
{            
    List<int> wordcount = new List<int>() { x.Count };
    foreach (int value in wordcount.Distinct())
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\"{0}\" occurs {1} time(s).", value, wordcount.Count(v => v == value));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
"2" occurs 1 time(s).
"2" occurs 1 time(s).
"2" occurs 1 time(s).
"2" occurs 1 time(s).
"2" occurs 1 time(s).
"2" occurs 1 time(s).
"2" occurs 1 time(s).
"2" occurs 1 time(s).
"2" occurs 1 time(s).
"2" occurs 1 time(s).
"1" occurs 1 time(s).
"1" occurs 1 time(s).
"1" occurs 1 time(s).
"1" occurs 1 time(s).
"1" occurs 1 time(s).
"1" occurs 1 time(s).
"1" occurs 1 time(s).
"1" occurs 1 time(s).
"1" occurs 1 time(s).
"1" occurs 1 time(s).
"1" occurs 1 time(s).
"1" occurs 1 time(s).
"1" occurs 1 time(s).
"1" occurs 1 time(s).
"1" occurs 1 time(s).
"1" occurs 1 time(s).
"1" occurs 1 time(s).
"1" occurs 1 time(s).
"1" occurs 1 time(s).
"1" occurs 1 time(s).
"1" occurs 1 time(s).
"1" occurs 1 time(s).
"1" occurs 1 time(s).
"1" occurs 1 time(s).
"1" occurs 1 time(s).
"1" occurs 1 time(s).
"1" occurs 1 time(s).
"1" occurs 1 time(s).
"1" occurs 1 time(s).
"1" occurs 1 time(s).
"1" occurs 1 time(s).
"1" occurs 1 time(s).
"1" occurs 1 time(s).
"1" occurs 1 time(s).
"1" occurs 1 time(s).
"1" occurs 1 time(s).
"1" occurs 1 time(s).
"1" occurs 1 time(s).
"1" occurs 1 time(s).
"1" occurs 1 time(s).
"1" occurs 1 time(s).
"1" occurs 1 time(s).
```

Answer (score 2):

You already have all the info in `q`. You should be able to simply print it:

```
foreach (var x in q)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\"{0}\" occurs {1} time(s).", x.Word, x.Count);
}
```

Comment: my command not show all, but actually in two foreach function. so can't use this command, i want to count duplicate in x.count.

Comment: In that case, I would suggest, that you update your question and show the actual code you use. It makes no sense to post something else.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't totally clear on what you were requesting, I answered your "Count Duplicate int in C-Sharp" statement more so than your example.

Is this what you're looking for?  There is a boolean for you to change it to show only duplicates (meaning there is more than 1 of a given number in the list) by leaving showAllNumbers as false or setting it to true, because I wasn't sure exactly what you were trying to do.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        List<int> numberCount = new List<int>(){52, 52, 15, 32, 52, 7, 9};
        bool showAllNumbers = true;
        var query = (from x in numberCount.GroupBy(intGroup => intGroup).Select(intGroupInfo => new {intLabel = intGroupInfo.Key, Count = intGroupInfo.Count()}) where (x.Count > 1 || showAllNumbers) select x);

        foreach(var groupCount in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("\"{0}\" occurs {1} times", groupCount.intLabel, groupCount.Count));
        }


    }
}
```

This results in something like this
"52" occurs 3 times
"15" occurs 1 times
"32" occurs 1 times
"7" occurs 1 times
"9" occurs 1 times

Comment: it can't work. because in two foreach function, it not allow to it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying, but it works just fine: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vaO1qW